# Android long running application

Tags: android, gps, long-integer

I'm trying to develop an application which posts the GPS coordinates with onLocationChange. My applications runs well, but when it goes to background it stops.  How I could keep running the application even if it goes to background?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use Service.See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to learn about service.See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) link also.